# Count number of values in nested lists inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
d= {
'2018-01-01': [[1.0],        [2.0],        [3.0]],
'2018-01-02': [[4.0],        [5.0],        [6.0]],
'2018-01-03': [[7.0],        [8.0],        [9.0]],
'2018-01-04': [[10.0],       [11.0],       [12.0]],
'2018-01-31': [[13.0, 14.0], [15.0, 16.0], [17.0]]
}
```

My aim is to count the number of values (floats in this case), assuming some of these 'cells' might contain more than one value (e.g.: values for `'2018-01-31'`). In other words, I need:

```
result=17
```

So far, I was able to count the number of 'cells' (sublists), but I can't find out how can I count several values inside a single 'cell'. I tried:

```
cols=len(d[[k for k in d.keys() if d[k]==max(d.values(),key=len)][0]])
cells = [[1 for j in range(cols)] for i in range(len(d))]
result = len([item for sublist in cells for item in sublist])

print(str(result))
```

**Output:**

```
15
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
100% flattening + `len`

```
>>> len([k for i in d.values() for j in i for k in j])
17
```

---

**Option 2**
`sum` + `len` + partial flattening
Use a `sum` with a generator comprehension. 3-list form:

```
>>> sum(len([*a, *b, *c]) for (a, b, c) in d.values())
17
```

For a the generic solution (with more/less than 3 sublists), use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> sum(len(list(chain.from_iterable(v))) for v in d.values())
17
```

Comment: Amazing! I definitely go for the generic one. I didnt mention sometimes the number of columns might vary, so that one is perfect... Thank you so much!

Comment: Im wondering if its posible not to count a value in case that value is 0.0 ¿...? I tried: `result=sum(len(list(chain.from_iterable(v))) for v in d.values() if v!=0)` but it didn't work (i just got the same result). Not a big need... just in case if you could point me out... that would be awesome!

Comment: @Victor replace chain.from_iterable(v) with filter(None, chain.from_iterable(v)), and see if that works?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Yes, sir!! It worked like a charm... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> len([c for a in d.values() for b in a for c in b])
17
```

you should really try these in an interactive interpreter, start from the simplest `[x for x in d.values()]` and work your way up.

Comment: Am I missing something? It seems our answers overlap... did you by chance edit because I don't remember seeing this. Apologies if I'm making a mistake here.

Comment: Edit history is public and timestamped. What's the matter? I didn't edit my answer by the way.

Comment: You can make edits within a 5 minute grace period. Anyway, I just wanted to let you know I didn't plagiarise your answer. Would you like me to remove it from my post?

Comment: I have absolutely no problem with that. It was very likely to come up with this solution, if one has a taste for one-liners and list comprehensions ;).

Comment: Cheers, I appreciate your understanding... if OP decides to use this answer, I hope they accept yours. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you guys! both of you are geniuses! Thank you very much! I've chosen the generic option above because sometimes I'd be in need of more 'columns'... MY FAULT not specifically mention it on the question. Sorry :-(( Once again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a flattened list for this task. This is one way:

```
from itertools import chain

res = sum(1 for _ in chain.from_iterable(map(chain.from_iterable, d.values())))
```

We deal with nested lists by applying `chain.from_iterable` twice and counting the results after this process.